# What algorithm is used in Set to avoid duplicates?

Tags: java, collections, set

May I know What algorithm is used in Set to avoid duplicates ?
I want to know just What is the name of the algorithm used to avoid the duplicates and If possible the same algorithm implementation as well.

Comment: depends on what `Set` implementation I would say

Comment: Just dive in the code of `Set` subclasses ... you will find the logics there.

Comment: You may want to take one step back and figure out the difference between interfaces and classes, and then head over to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (since all the information you need is there).

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is found here;
https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/gj/doc/java.util.Set.html#add(A)

Adds the specified element to this Set if it is not already present (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element, o, to the Set if the Set contains no element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)). If the Set already contains the specified element, the call leaves the Set unchanged (and returns false). In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that Sets never contain duplicate elements.

Comment: The optional part is that it will not override the previous one.  "More formally, adds the specified element, o, to the Set if the Set contains no element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))"

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the Set implementation. [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is just an interface that defines the methods and general behavior of implementing classes. How this classes ensure the uniqueness of the entries depends on the implementation of this classes and can be quite different.

Some implementation could use an sorted list to quickly find an existing entry by using a binary search, some other class might be stupid and will just iterate over every entry to find out if an entry already exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

The HashSet implementation have a HashMap as the data.

You can see that add(E e) will call map.put(e, DUMMY) where the HashMap implementation relies on the obejct hashCode() and equals() methods for its key uniquiness so any object with returns trues for equals will replace the previous one.

The implementation of this Set can be seen here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java

Comment: This answer is not complete and not fully correct. It is not only the hash code. It looks at `hashCode()` as well as `equals()`. Note that hash codes are not unique keys - different objects may have the same hash code.